# ANALYZE or OPTIMIZE first in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

As the title suggests what is the correct order of operation to optimize performance on a table in Databricks? I see some claiming OPTIMIZE TABLE then ANALYZE TABLE and others claiming the opposite. Does order matter?

Thanks

EDIT: When I say optimize, it's more to do with Z-ORDERING.
What's interesting is that Z-ORDERING will fail if there is no statistics gathered, so does that suggest ANALYZE should be performed first?

Comment: optimize relies on data generated by analyze, so analyze->optimize and probably analyze again